# Convolution and classification model in main model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have to create model of neural network, like this:

```
convolution --> classification
       \            /
        \          /
        _\|      |/_
         third model
       with one output
```

Convolution outputs data, which is used as input to classification model. After that, convolution and classification outputs are filled (concatenate) to third model. Third model will output prediction 0..1, which is used to train **whole** network.

- First of all: **Is it possible to back-propagate classification model correctly, in this situation?** Or this require to create three separated models?
- I have tried to concatenate convolution and classification but with no good results. I got "Graph disconnected" error.

Full log of error:
"Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("classification_prediction_Input_2:0", shape=(1, 512), dtype=float32) at layer "classification_prediction_Input". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []".

If idea is correct, how to connect models like on "graphic"?

My code at now:

```
# state convolution
state_input = Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE, name='state_input', batch_shape=(1, 210, 160, 3))
state_Conv2D_1 = Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(8, 8), strides=(4, 4), activation='relu', name='state_Conv2D_1')(state_input)
state_MaxPooling2D_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='state_MaxPooling2D_1')(state_Conv2D_1)
state_outputs = Flatten(name='state_Flatten')(state_MaxPooling2D_1)
state_convolution_model = Model(state_input, state_outputs, name='state_convolution_model')
state_convolution_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['acc'])

state_convolution_model_input = Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE, name='state_convolution_model_input', batch_shape=(1, 210, 160, 3))
state_convolution = state_convolution_model(state_convolution_model_input)

# classification output
classficication_Input = Input(shape=(1, LSTM_OUTPUT_DIM), batch_shape=(1, LSTM_OUTPUT_DIM), name='classification_prediction_Input')
classficication_Dense_1 = Dense(32, activation='relu', name='classification_prediction_Dense_1')(classficication_Input)
classficication_output_raw = Dense(ACTIONS, activation='sigmoid', name='classification_output_raw')(classficication_Dense_1)
classficication_output = Reshape((ACTIONS,), name='classification_output')(classficication_output_raw)
classficication_model = Model(classficication_Input, classficication_output, name='classificationPrediction_model')
classficication_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

classficicationPrediction = classficication_model(state_convolution)

i = keras.layers.concatenate([state_outputs, classficication_output], name='concatenate')
d = Dense(32, activation='relu')(i)
o = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(d)
model = Model(state_input, o)                  # <-- graph error is here
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
```

Comment: What are LSTM_OUTPUT_DIM, ACTIONS? Could you post a minimal working example so I can run it and reproduce the error?

Comment: Integers. Can be 64 (LSTM_OUTPUT_DIM) and 4 (ACTIONS)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build a structure like this and train it in end-to-end fashion. However, you need to create a single model that has several branches. Another problem I can see is that you compile model before it is fully defined. Here is working code:

```
# state convolution                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
state_input = Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE, name='state_input')
state_Conv2D_1 = Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(8, 8), strides=(4, 4), activation='relu', name='state_Conv2D_1')(state_input)
state_MaxPooling2D_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='state_MaxPooling2D_1')(state_Conv2D_1)
state_outputs = Flatten(name='state_Flatten')(state_MaxPooling2D_1)

# classification output                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
classification_Dense_1 = Dense(32, activation='relu', name='classification_prediction_Dense_1')(state_outputs)
classification_output_raw = Dense(ACTIONS,                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                  activation='sigmoid',                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                  name='classification_output_raw')(classification_Dense_1)
classification_output = Reshape((ACTIONS,), name='classification_output')(classification_output_raw)


i = concatenate([state_outputs, classification_output], name='concatenate')
d = Dense(32, activation='relu')(i)
o = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(d)
model = Model(state_input, o)                  # <-- no graph error anymore here                                                                                                                                                                                      
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
state_input (InputLayer)        (None, 210, 160, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
state_Conv2D_1 (Conv2D)         (None, 51, 39, 8)    1544        state_input[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
state_MaxPooling2D_1 (MaxPoolin (None, 25, 19, 8)    0           state_Conv2D_1[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
state_Flatten (Flatten)         (None, 3800)         0           state_MaxPooling2D_1[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
classification_prediction_Dense (None, 32)           121632      state_Flatten[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
classification_output_raw (Dens (None, 4)            132         classification_prediction_Dense_1
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
classification_output (Reshape) (None, 4)            0           classification_output_raw[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 3804)         0           state_Flatten[0][0]              
                                                                 classification_output[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 32)           121760      concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            33          dense[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
```

See [Guide to the Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) for more examples.